# How can I split a string into multiple variables in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, variables, split, character

I want to be able to split each character of the string "Hello World" into multiple variables.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you really want to split each character to multiple variables, or do you want to split each character to a separate variable? I'm guessing the latter, but as you haven't been bothered to make any effort to try anything how are we supposed to know?

Answer (score 0):

Always put a "^" (without quotes) after the string you want to split. Also you must put the string in the str variable

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set str="Hello World^!"
set tempstr=%str%
set count=0
:loop
if defined tempstr (
    set tempstr=%tempstr:~1%
    set /a count+=1
    set /a pos=%count%-1
    set t!count!=!str:~%pos%,1!
    goto loop
)
```